# Webpack Output Messaging

Tags: webpack

Webpack outputs a lot and it gets frustrating when trying to debug. I figured out a way to shut the messages off with `stats: 'errors-only'` in my `moldule.export`. However this also removed my js linting - how can I allow my linting messages, but none from webpack?

Comment: instead of `errors-only` have you tried `stats: {chunks:false}`? This might tone down the amount of information displayed and will not get rid of linting messages.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `minimal` and that worked!